# jquery animation to move a p tag up certain height

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Animation working here but i want to move facebook only 10% top and stay but its dis appering out, i want i to stay after animation and slowly login form fades in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.login").hide();
$("p").slideUp(1000);
$("div.login").fadeIn(3000);
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
*{margin:0; padding:0}
html, body {
color: #F00;
background-color: #333;
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.logo{width:100%; height:40%;}
p{font-size:200%; text-align:center; padding-top:20%}
.login{width:100%; height:60%; text-align:center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="logo"><p>facebook</p></div>
 <div class="login">
    <ul>
        <li><label for="username">Username</label><input type="text"    placeholder="you@email.com" autofocus required /></li>
        <li><label for="Password">Password</label><input type="password" placeholder="you@email.com" autofocus required /></li>
        <li><button>Login</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe not mine to ask but why would you want to annoy the user like that? Also.. isolate your stuff. Don't mix css, html and javascript together in the same file.

Comment: Are you trying to phish for Facebook logins?

Comment: I doubt it since Facebook doesn't bother with pointless fade-ing (I think?).

Comment: Try using absolute positions for your divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .slide up()

Description: Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.
```

[JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

If I understand your question correctly you actually want to be using `.animate()`

```
$('p').animate({'top':'-50px'}, 1000);
```

tweak to suit the height of your element